# Select form with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I would like to get select form with variable amount of fields. To achive this first I connect to db and converting data from php to javascript. Then i got array (wynik) with values, but when i try to print it i get empty select form and all values shown next to it. There is my javascript function:

```
<script language="javascript">
function addInput() {
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<select name='add' /><br />";
for (i=0;i<wynik.length;i++)
{
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<option value=" + "wynik[i]" + " />" + wynik[i] + "</option />";
}
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "</select />";
}
</script>
```

And HTML code:

```
<form name="add" action="add_form.php" method="post">
<div id="text">
</div>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="addInput()" name="add" value="Add value" />
```

Please help me to put that into form.

Comment: `<script language="javascript">`? This is not 1997, please don't write HTML 3.2.

Comment: @Quentin wow, you could tell that this is 3.2 just by that?

Comment: @pattyd — HTML 2 didn't have script elements. HTML 4 made the type attribute mandatory. I'm being somewhat facetious, the big pile of rogue `/`s mean that it is horrible tag soup rather than HTML 3.2. The real message is *Write proper HTML*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser will attempt to fix the DOM each time you write HTML to it, consequently *you cannot write **just** a start tag to `innerHTML`.*

Build all your HTML up in a string and then insert it in one go.

Better yet, use `createElement`, `appendChild` and friends instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to remove `<br />` after `<select name='add' />` . Also `</select />` does not need a / in the end (it has it in the begining) - `</select>`.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach you can try with ajax:

```
<!-- Script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#add").on('click', function(){
       $.ajax({
            url     : 'ajax.php',
            type    : 'POST',
            success : function(resp){
                $("#backend").html(resp);
            },
            error   : function(resp){

            }
       }); 
    });
});
</script>
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="text"><select id="backend" name=""></select></div>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add value" />

<!-- Backend ajax.php -->
<?php
#your query here to fetch $wynik
$str    = "";
foreach($wynik as $value){
    $str    .= '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}
return $str;
```